# Почему в wordpress не подгружаются файлы к постам?

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток, не отображаются файлы добавленные к записям причем как в браузере так и в панели управления. После добавления или редактирования записи все нормально, а через 6-12 часов картинок нет.
ошибка в консоли браузера Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
[image: создание записи]

а через некоторое время

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и
[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Покажите скриншоты, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Comment: В Интернет нет такого адреса `http://wordpress/wp-content` и т.д. У вас неправильно настроен сайт

Comment: Спасибо, самое очевидное я не вижу)